# multiple clients silmuntaneously on sesame repository

Tags: sesame

i use sesame for a project and i use a local nativestore file repository. everything is fine but when multiple clients use my application silmuntaneusly the repository locks.How can i deal with parallel connections problem;

Answer (score 1):

A Sesame Native Store assumes it has sole, unique access to its datadir. This means that you can not create two NativeStore objects that use the same datadir, as this will cause inconsistencies and potential deadlocks. So, you need to share a single NativeStore object.

In a single JRE, this can be easily achieved by using a `RepositoryManager`. See [this article](http://rivuli-development.com/further-reading/sesame-cookbook/the-repositorymanager/) for an explanation and code examples. If your setup requires several independent client applications to connect to Sesame, you will either have to implement your own server app for these clients to connect to, or you can use a Sesame Server and have each client connect via a `HTTPRepository`.